# connection to a remote mysql database using node

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection

Good mornig to you guys. I want to establish a connection to a remote mysql database using node js. but i am facing this error. I do not know if I wrongly specifies the access path to the db

## code

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: "http://kamerun-it.com/mysql",
  connectionLimit : 100,
  database: "****",
  user: "****",
  password: "*****",
  multipleStatements: true

});
```

## error

```
  throw err;
  ^
```

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http://kamerun-it.com/mysql
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (F:\kamerun it\aspi-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (F:\kamerun it\aspi-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at PoolConnection.connect (F:\kamerun it\aspi-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:119:18)
    at Pool.getConnection (F:\kamerun it\aspi-api\node_modules\mysql\lib\Pool.js:48:16)
    at Object. (F:\kamerun it\aspi-api\app\model\db.js:16:8)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19) {
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'http://kamerun-it.com/mysql',
  fatal: true
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an error in your config with the host URL.

Here's a working example with a connection to a remote MySQL:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

const connection = mysql.createPool({
  host: "remotemysql.com",
  user: "aKlLAqAfXH",
  password: "PZKuFVGRQD",
  database: "aKlLAqAfXH"
});

connection.query(
  "SELECT hexcode FROM colours WHERE precedence = 2",
  (err, result) => {
    err ? console.log(err) : console.log(result[0].hexcode);
  }
);
```

and here's one with mistaken host parameter:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");

const connection = mysql.createPool({
  host: "WRONGremotemysql.com",
  user: "aKlLAqAfXH",
  password: "PZKuFVGRQD",
  database: "aKlLAqAfXH"
});

connection.query(
  "SELECT hexcode FROM colours WHERE precedence = 2",
  (err, result) => {
    err ? console.log(err) : console.log(result[0].hexcode);
  }
);
```

The second one returns the same `ENOTFOUND` error.

Check if that's the correct URL, if the database can be accessed remotely and via which port you can use it.

Comment: when i am going to the host url **http://kamerun-it.com/mysql**,I can access my database by entering credentials ( **is ok to confirm that the url is correct and the database can be accessed remotely ?? **)

Comment: you access phpmyadmin portal which is running on web port 80, remote access to a db is different. No, it's correct to say it can be accessed remotely.

Comment: remote access is different?? how to access this database in my case

Comment: if you want to use it via script that's not on the same server - that's remote access. It should be allowed/configured by your hosting provider or sysadmin or you enable it if you have access to mysql configs